# I want to scale android uri file

Tags: android, file, uri, scale

I'm sorry for my english level
I want to scale android uri file in gallery.  I can do with decodeSampledBitmapFromResource. But this wants resID. I have a file path available. How can I do scaled image and storage or Is there any different method?When I download user photos I want   data saving and speed saving.

```
static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources _Resources, int resID, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final BitmapFactory.Options _Options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    _Options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(_Resources, resID, _Options);
    _Options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(_Options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
    _Options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(_Resources, resID, _Options);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a content URI, you can use `ContentResolver` to open the the input stream and `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` to read the bitmap. The equivalent here should be:

```
static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromURI(Uri imageUri, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final BitmapFactory.Options _Options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    _Options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, _Options);

    _Options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(_Options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
    _Options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    // Note that we need to open the input stream again here
    inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, _Options);
}
```